# Keep VGA signal sending when using VGA switchbox

Tags: vga, signal, switchbox

I am trying to mimic the VGA projector setup I had on Arch
Linux.  I have three laptops connected through a VGA switchbox to an external projector.  When I was using ArchLinux I used xrandr to start using the projector and when, afterwards, switching to another laptop and back, the VGA signal was still transmitting on the first laptop so that I could switch directly back to this first signal.
Now on Ubuntu the laptop seems to "redo" the connection to the projector whenever I switch back to it, and this way the projector shows its "off"screen for some seconds and needs to resync to the laptops VGA channel... very disturbing when doing live VJ sessions...

Does anyone know how to make the VGA signal continuous after its first setup?  Which package does the external monitor switching in Ubuntu (maybe I can turn it off?)  Or other solutions for going back to direct VGA switching (as in ArchLinux)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem, I found out, can be found here :

[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1516048&highlight=forcing+vga+signal](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1516048&highlight=forcing%20vga%20signal)

In short:

Add "video=VGA-1:e" to the "linux" (kernel) line in grub configuration :  the output VGA1 will now be set to send a signal continuously...